# Autoit - Validate windows share user authentication

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to connect to a windows share (\print) but if my authentication fails, for example, wrong username or password, how can i catch that error?
The problem is that when executing the script (exe. file), if i insert wrong credentials, the error message is from Autoit program and not the message i would like to pop up (code above) if there is some problem with the authentication.

Here is a sample of my code:

Here I try connect to the server \print with username and password

```
$WshNetwork = ObjCreate("WScript.Network")
$WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive("", "\\print", True, $username, $password)
```

The values of $username and $password are filled from an Inputbox.
So, after that code i tried to catch the error like this:

```
if @error Then
    MsgBox(16, "", "Authentication error!")
EndIf
```

And by the way, the error i got from the console is this one:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.au3 (33) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.:
$WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive( "","\\print",True, $username, $password)
$WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive( "","\\print",True, $username, $password)^ ERROR
```

Well, the error is happening, but is there some way to catch the error from the code and send an alert (Msgbox)?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`DriveMapAdd(...)`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DriveMapAdd.htm) in AutoIt. Or try using something like this:

```
$USERNAME = InputBox(...)
$PASSWORD = InputBox(...)
$DRIVEINPUTBOX = InputBox(...)
$SHARE = "\\print\foldername"
$DRIVE = $DRIVEINPUTBOX & ": "

$COMMAND = "NET USE " & $DRIVE & " " & $SHARE & " /USER:" & $USERNAME & " " & $PASSWORD & " > TEMP"

RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $COMMAND)

; Read the file "TEMP"
; Choose what to do
; Delete file "TEMP"
```